# Reprojected raster return only zeros from QGIS raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am experiencing an issue when trying to use my reprojected raster in QGIS raster calculator; First, my raster is reprojected from degrees to meters. After that, I want to process the layer by applying calculations on it in QGIS raster calculator. However, the output layer is simply a layer filled with zeroes. Even when I simply multiply the reprojected layer with 1 this is the outcome. Any suggestions on what might be the reason for this?

Comment: Have you made sure the boundaries of the calculation area are correct?